# Upper bound of $f^{n}$ (f and its derivates)

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the upperbound of $f^{n}$, for $f = e^{-x} * cos(4\pi x)$

How is this done?

Kind regards

Comment: Depends if you want just one bound or the sharpest bound. If you just want to bound it then Leibnitz rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) is useful.

Comment: Not the sharpest bound, just one bound. Will try to look into the theorem

Comment: Ok then that will do. You can compute the $k$'th derivative of both $e^{-x}$ and $\cos(4\pi x)$ and then simply take the absolute value of each term in that sum (the triangle inequality) to get your bound. For this is useful to remember that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are bounded by $1$ and the binomial theorem might also be useful in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $f(x)=Re(e^{(-1+4\pi i)x})$ and thus
$$f^{(n)}(x)=Re((-1+4\pi i)^ne^{(-1+4\pi i)x}),$$
giving a bound of
$$
|f^{(n)}(x)|\le |(-1+4\pi i)^ne^{(-1+4\pi i)x})|=(1+16\pi^2)^{n/2}e^{-x}
$$

Comment: Where do you get $f(x) = Re(e^{(-1+4\pi i)x} from?$

Comment: Because $\cos(u)=Re(e^{iu})$. Or $e^{iu}=\cos u+i\sin u$.

Comment: How do you end up getting $(1+ 16*\pi^2)^{n/2}e^{-x}$?

Comment: As $|-1+4\pi i|=\sqrt{1+16\pi^2}$ and $|e^{a+ib}|=e^a$.